# NVIDIA G92GLM Quadro FX3800M problems on Ubuntu 16.04 kernels

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, graphics

Having continued problems for the last three months with display flickering between TTY login screens and a black X-screen after every kernel update?

Comment: Glad to see you want to share your findings, but Stack Exchange isn't a forum. You need to split this into a question and an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The fix is to go to recovery mode, enable network, install intel-microcode, purge nvidia and install nvidia-340, or just reinstall nvidia-340 if it says is already installed and reboot.